# MongoDB: slow removeShard

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a MongoDB cluster with 9 nodes (3 shards, 3 nodes each). I'm now removing one shard, but the process itself is running extremely slow. Each node of the shard being deleted stores ~400Gb of data, which isn't too much, I suppose. But approximation shows that the process of draining finishes in 200+ days.

I was wondering if there is a way to speed up this process. I have enough free resources (CPU, Mem, IO), I mean 3x more than nodes consume now. I've already looked at balancers settings like `_secondaryThrottle` or `_waitForDelete` without much success.

MongoDB 4.4.13

Comment: Did you disable balancing for any collection?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit no, I didn’t

Comment: Did you follow [Remove Shards from an Existing Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/remove-shards-from-cluster/)? Perhaps you need to run [cleanupOrphaned](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/cleanupOrphaned/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.cleanupOrphaned)

Comment: I completely follow the official documentation. Also, I'm using Mongo 4.4 which has no need to run `cleanupOrphaned` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, during analyzing events in `changelog` MongoDB waits too long on the transfer step inside every `MoveChunk.to`/`MoveChunk.from` event.

For now, MongoDB can't guarantee consistency for queries on secondaries that have been started before chunk migration with anything other than `sleep`. By default, MongoDB just waits for 15 minutes before deleting a chunk from secondary and moving on. So a migration of every chunk took >15min.

Moreover, MongoDB has had an issue for about 5 years.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/parameters/#mongodb-parameter-param.orphanCleanupDelaySecs

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31837